# What services let me query big data and let me provide a non-simple query code

Tags: real-time, bigdata

I would like to create huge data sets (25 ints a row, 30 rows per second, multiply that by 60).
On the other hand, I want to query it for rows that match a certain condition (e.g. rows that not more than 5 ints of the 25 are out of a certain range).

And I want it all in real time, i.e. inserting and querying continuously.

Does someone know how to do it, preferably using a cloud service (Amazon? Google?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try one-tick, though its designed for market pricing data, I think it can be adapted to other forms of high frequency data. You can then build filtering/aggregation rules that can help you analyze the data

Comment: I can't see anywhere they're giving a service, do I need to install anything?